# Add total SUM from VLOOKUP?

Tags: excel

I've got 3 columns as follows:

```
Boolean          Value          Date
Yes               £3000         01-Jan-2012
No                £3000         01-Jan-2012
No                £3000         01-Nov-2012
```

Basically I just need to look at that table and come up with the total value for where Boolean is set to No, however only take those where the month is equal or less than the current month set by the computer time

Comment: you can use subtotal function in data

Comment: Sorry - just edited it as tried than and realised its not quite what I wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Excel? In Excel 2007 and later try SUMIFS which allows you to sum with multiple conditions, i.e.

`=SUMIFS(B2:B10,A2:A10,"No",C2:C10,"<="&TODAY())`

I used cell references but you can used named ranges in their place like this:

`=SUMIFS(Value,Boolean,"No",Date,"<="&TODAY())`

or in earlier versions of Excel you can use SUMPRODUCT like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B10,(A2:A10="No")*(C2:C10<=TODAY()))`

Comment: Thanks.  Im using Excel 2007.  I've tried using SUMIFS however it returns the #VALUE! error.  Not too sure why.  Could it because by values, boolean and dates are generates using forumlas?

Comment: #VALUE! probably means that your ranges are different sizes - all ranges in SUMIFS need to be the same size and shape, are you using defined names or actual cell references?

Comment: Im using cell references.  My forumla is =SUMIFS($K$19:$L$31,$O$19:$O$31,"No",$M$19:$N$31,"<="&TODAY())  As you can see from the formula, some cells are merged.  Would this affect the outcome?

Comment: Yes, those ranges are different sizes, hence #VALUE error, if columns K and L and also M and N are merged you can normally refer to those by the first column of the two, try `=SUMIFS($K$19:$K$31,$O$19:$O$31,"No",$M$19:$M$31,"<="&TODAY())` - Personally I would always avoid merged cells in most areas - they can cause problems for calculations

Comment: OK so I've got that working.  It calculates it correctly, however when im on a row where the date is say November 2012, it still shows the total when I was hoping it wouldn't show anything.  How can I go about achieving that?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - the total shouldn't include any values for dates in the future - are you saying that it does or do you want different outputs for different rows depending on where you put the formula?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`DSUM`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/dsum-HP005209069.aspx) function.

Criteria range would be

```
Boolean         Month Check
No              =MONTH(C2) < X
```

where `C2` is the first data cell in column `Date`.